# Does the Google Play Console log all crashes?

Tags: android, console, crash

I have a crash that has slowly crept up in crash rate over my last few releases. All attempts to fix the crash have proved futile. I suspect that the crash happens in the background and users are not actually seeing the issue, else I would have many more reviews about the app crashing.

Do users still need to tap the the crash module that pops up in order for Google to log the crash or does the crash report get sent automatically at this point?

I can not find a definitive answer to this.

Here is the crash if anyone has ideas. There is a lot of info available on that I have tried as well as anything else I could think of. Dug through every SDK, reverted back to previous target API, turned off features etc etc :(

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occurred while executing doInBackground()
at
android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:354)
at
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:383)
at
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:252)
at
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:271)
at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
at
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:798)
Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: Caller no longer running, last stopped +2s531ms because: timed out while starting
at
android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:1950)
at
android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1918)
at
android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1868)
at
android.app.job.IJobCallback$Stub$Proxy.dequeueWork(IJobCallback.java:195)
at
android.app.job.JobParameters.dequeueWork(JobParameters.java:243)
at
androidx.core.app.JobIntentService$JobServiceEngineImpl.dequeueWork(:4)
at
androidx.core.app.JobIntentService.dequeueWork(:2)
at
androidx.core.app.JobIntentService$CommandProcessor.doInBackground(:2)
at
androidx.core.app.JobIntentService$CommandProcessor.doInBackground(:1)
at
android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:333)
at
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
at
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
at
java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:798)
Caused by: android.os.RemoteException: Remote stack trace:
at
com.android.server.job.JobServiceContext.assertCallerLocked(JobServiceContext.java:481)
at
com.android.server.job.JobServiceContext.doDequeueWork(JobServiceContext.java:359)
at
com.android.server.job.JobServiceContext$JobCallback.dequeueWork(JobServiceContext.java:160)
at
android.app.job.IJobCallback$Stub.onTransact(IJobCallback.java:83)
at
android.os.Binder.execTransact(Binder.java:746)
```

Comment: Hi, I am having the same problem. Do you also have a home screen widget? Did you solve it?